# How to exclude files from JavaScript language service in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I get the following message in Visual Studio:

```
The JavaScript language service has been disabled for the following project(s): Images.
These files exceeded the program size threshold: .\Images\static\js\main.js.
```

I've tried to exclude the `main.js` file by adding it into tsconfig.json, but I still get the warning:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": false,
    "watch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": [ "dom", "es6", "es2017", "es2018" ],
    "target": "es5" // IE11 safe
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/main.js"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Would this help?https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bc9ba05a-e2a6-4279-bcee-c7caa3a70369/repeated-warning-quotthe-javascript-language-service-has-been-disabled-for-the-following?forum=vssetup

Comment: @v2103 The thread is for an older version of VS, but the discussion there did lead me to a place that might yield something useful.

Comment: glad that it helped :)